# Error al agregar una DLL a un proyecto Windows Form C#

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de usar una dll de una liberia externa, pero al tratar de agregar la referencia al proyecto me sale el error adjunto en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las DLL se agrega solas cuando compilas la aplicación

Comment: son DLL de una Liberia externa

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy usando una libereria para mi proyecto esta libreria para funcionar necesita de una dll Externas, las cuales estoy copiando y pegando en mi carpeta bin\debug para que me funcione la libreria, como puedo hacer que estas dll una vez compile mi proyecto se copien automaticamente, trate de agregarlas por medio de referencias pero me sale el error de la imagen, por lo general cuando agrego referencias estas no me presentan problemas y se compilan en el ejecutable, estas dll no he podido añadirlas